# Why is my seam app only deploying partially?

Tags: jsf, jboss, seam, jsf-1.2

I have a seam app that my colleague created. It is maven-based.  I'm trying to get make it work in eclipse which is baffling in itself, but I managed to get rid of all the eclipse "Problems" (as displayed in the problem view) and the app builds successfully, both from the command line and from within eclipse.

The difficulty is when I deploy the app to the jboss server (Jboss 5.1) the deployment only gets as far as JSF and never starts the Seam section.  So the logfile looks like this

```
13:15:23,087 INFO  [EJBContainer] STARTED EJB: org.jboss.seam.transaction.EjbSynchronizations ejbName: EjbSynchronizations
13:15:23,107 INFO  [JndiSessionRegistrarBase] Binding the following Entries in Global JNDI:

nccm-app/EjbSynchronizations/local - EJB3.x Default Local Business Interface
nccm-app/EjbSynchronizations/local-org.jboss.seam.transaction.LocalEjbSynchronizations - EJB3.x Local Business Interface

13:15:23,357 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/nccm
13:15:23,448 INFO  [config] Initializing Mojarra (1.2_13-b01-FCS) for context '/nccm'`
```

and stops.  A working app continues with seam:

```
2011-09-16 11:59:48,494 INFO  [javax.servlet.ServletContextListener] (HDScanner) Welcome to Seam 2.2.0.EAP5
```

Something must be missing in my EAR file, but I can't figure out what.  The seam library is definitely there.  Any way to tell what I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

Hanging on `Initializing Mojarra` can mean at least 2 things:

1. There is not enough memory. Increase your container's heap space. Start at 512M, depending on your webapp's size.
2. There is a conflict in JSF-related libraries. Ensure that all versions are compatible with each other (JSF, Seam, RichFaces, etc). Ensure that you understand that JBoss ships with its own set of JSF api/impl libraries and that you should not include any in your webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib` (i.e. mark it as `provided` in Maven). Or, if you want to override JBoss from loading its builtin JSF libs and prefer the webapp-included libraries, then you should add the following context parameter to the webapp's `web.xml` to tell JBoss to use the WAR-bundled JSF impl instead:

   ```xml
   <context-param>
       <param-name>org.jboss.jbossfaces.WAR_BUNDLES_JSF_IMPL</param-name>
       <param-value>true</param-value>
   </context-param>
   ```

Comment: thank you for your answer. you always know what you are talking about. here's what I just discovered. somehow in diddling around with eclipse I decimated my web.xml file. When I restored it, the entire deploy worked. I'm not entirely sure which part is critical, but all the servlet mappings were gone.

Comment: OK, it works now? Interesting. Did you also have JSF-related `<listener>` entries in `web.xml` which also disappeared?

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have `seam.properties` file (may be empty) in your resulting files.

For `war` assemblies it should be presented here:

```
\WEB-INF\classes\seam.properties
```

For `jar` assemblies (which have seam bean declarations) it should be here:

```
\classes\seam.properties
```